# Proxy sub.domain.com/link1 -> 10.1.1.1:8080/someotherlink1

Tags: proxy, nginx

Trying to do a simple proxy from 
`sub.domain.com/link1` to another server `10.1.1.1:8080/someotherlink1`.

This is what my server context looks like: (I modified the default nginx.conf)

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  sub.domain.com;
    root         /;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location /link1 {      
        proxy_pass http://10.1.1.1:8080/link2
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

`

but visiting a webpage is just loading the nginx 502 bad gateway page.

Error in the log is:

`2017/03/15 22:04:27 [crit] 8647#0: *11 connect() to 10.1.1.1:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 112.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: sub.domain.com, request: "GET /link1/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.1.1.1.1:8080/link2/", host: "sub.domain.com"`

What's a bit strange looking is the `GET /link1/` - as this this should not be the link in the final upstream URL - it should not be trying to get this link.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You do not pass the URI on the `proxy_pass` directive, you need to first rewrite or redirect then pass it to the proxy, for example:

```
location /link1 {
  return 301 $scheme://$http_host/link2$args;
}

location /link2 {
  proxy_pass http://10.1.1.1:8080;
}
```